# Dynamic Data inside MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling, database, nosql

I'm making dynamic data storage, which it was in relational data base as:

```
form -> field
form -> form_data
field -> field_data
form_data -> filed_data
```

and field data contains field_id, form_data_id, and value

but for scalability and performance I'm planing to move form_data and field_data to MongoDB and my problem now is how to design MongoDB collections, using one collection for all form_data and move field_data to map inside it and key is field_id and value is the value of this field_data, or make collection for each form record and store data direct in form_data without map as the all data in this case will be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

In document-oriented databases like MongoDB you should always favor aggregation over references, because they don't support JOIN-operations on the database to link multiple documents.

That means that a "A has many B" relationship between two entities should not be modeled as two tables A and B, but rather as one collection of A where each A has an embedded array of B objects.

In the context of MongoDB, there is however an additional limitation: MongoDB doesn't like objects which grow. When an object accumulates more and more data over its lifetime, the object will grow. That means that the hard drive space MongoDB allocated for it will run out again and again, which will require space reallocation. This takes performance and fragments the database. Also, MongoDB has an artificial size limit for documents, mainly to discourage developers from designing growing objects.

Therefor:

**When the data exists at creation, embed it directly.**

**When more and more data is added after creation, put it into a different collection.**

When a form has X fields, the number of fields will likely not change much over its lifetime. So you should embed the fields and their descriptions directly into the form object.

But the number of answers entered into these forms will grow over time, which means that these should be treated as separate objects in a separate collection.

So I would recommend you to have two collections, `forms` and `form_data`.

Each document in `forms` embeds a sub-object of `fields` with the static field properties.

Each document in `form_data` has a field with the _id of the corresponding form and embeds a sub-object of `field_data` which uses the same keys as the `fields` sub-object of `forms` and stores the entries the user made in that form.

When your use-case requires frequent access to the aggregated data (like when you want to publish the up-to-date statistics on a public website), you could also store this information in the fields of `forms` to avoid an expensive aggregation query over many `form_data` documents. MongoDB in general recommends to orient your database schema rather on your performance requirements than on the semantics of your data.

Regarding your remark *"all data in this case will be consistent"*: keep in mind that MongoDB does not enforce referential integrity. When an application deletes or changes a document, it's the responsibility of the application to fix any outdated references to it in other documents.

Comment: thanks Philipp actually I'm planning to use JPA for forms and fields to get benefit of caching and as it is not frequently changing, and for data I'm going to use MongoDB for scalability as the data is going to grow,and here is my question, is it recommended to make one "collection" for all form_data or it is better to make "collection" for each form type?

Comment: Remember that you can't query more than one collection at a time. So unless you are absolutely sure that each form is a completely separated application and you are never going to cross-reference them, you should put them all into one collection.

Comment: My application is dynamically handle different forms using REST interface so I'm going to deal with relations as rest URLs so there is no relation required on MongoDB level between form-data entities, but I have to provide concurrently access for all form types.

Comment: Just to make sure there are no misunderstandings: With "one collection at a time" I did not mean that you can't run multiple queries in parallel. I was referring to the query language which doesn't allow you to search multiple collections with one command.